# Create a JOI schema validation based on a Param name conditional to determine corresponding Schema

Tags: node.js, express, schema, joi

Looking to create a Joi Schema validation based off the param name to select corresponding schema to validate

Not Hapi/Joi

The params will either be ***full-time***,  ***contract-associate***, ***intern-associate***, ***seasonal-associate***

The Schemas are attached below

```
var associate = Joi.object().keys({
    Job_title: Joi.string().required(),
    work_information: Joi.object().keys({
        Full_Name: Joi.string().required(),
        Email_Address: Joi.string().required(),
        phone_number: Joi.string().required(),
        company_Name: Joi.string().required(),
        manager_information: Joi.string().required(),
        gender: Joi.string().required(),
        Date_of_Birth: Joi.string().required(),
        manager_information: Joi.string().required(),
    })
});

var intern = Joi.object().keys({
    Job_title: Joi.string().required(),
    work_information: Joi.object().keys({
        Full_Name: Joi.string().required(),
        Email_Address: Joi.string().required(),
        phone_number: Joi.string().required(),
        company_Name: Joi.string().required(),
        manager_information: Joi.string().required(),
        gender: Joi.string().required(),
        Date_of_Birth: Joi.string().required(),
        manager_information: Joi.string().required(),
        university_name: Joi.string().required(),
        date_of_graduation: Joi.string().required(),
    })
});

var contractor = Joi.object().keys({
    Job_title: Joi.string().required(),
    work_information: Joi.object().keys({
        Full_Name: Joi.string().required(),
        Email_Address: Joi.string().required(),
        phone_number: Joi.string().required(),
        consulting_agency: Joi.string().required(),
    })
});

var seasonal = Joi.object().keys({
    Job_title: Joi.string().required(),
    work_information: Joi.object().keys({
        Full_Name: Joi.string().required(),
        Email_Address: Joi.string().required(),
        phone_number: Joi.string().required(),
        duration_of_employment: Joi.string().required(),
        manager_information: Joi.string().required(),
    })
});
```

Here's what I have so

```
var createAssociateProfile = Joi.object({
params: Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().valid('full-time', 'contract-associate', 'intern-associate', 'seasonal-associate' ).required()
}),
body: Joi.object({
    Job_title: Joi.string().required(),
    work_information: Joi.object().required().when('params.name', 
            { is: 'full-time', then: associate },
            { is: 'contract-associate', then: intern},
            { is: 'intern-associate', then: contractor},
            { is: 'seasonal-associate', then: seasonal},
    )
})
```

});

Comment: What is your question ? As you have already attached a solution, do you want a more optimized one ?

Comment: The solution is my current progress, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

By using `.when('params.name')` you are refereeing to a peer inside the `work_information` object.

To reference the first `params` object, you should do:

```
.when('...params.name')
```

`...` is a reference to the grand-parent.

Here are more details about relative references:

https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#relative-references

Comment: This does not seem to work. When testing the Joi schema by opting out a required field, the joi schema fails to throw an error

Comment: @Pfizer what is the error?

Comment: when validating a schema by accessing an endpoint, it seems to give us the success response we're looking for. However, if you omit a required field from the request, the JOI validation does not return a error for the missing field. My thoughts are that there is no schema validation taking place.